# Django Multi-User logins - best approach?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, database-relations

I'm currently developing a Django site in which users can have multiple 'accounts', so that they can seamlessly switch between different public profiles when interacting through the site. What I'm designing is likely to attract multiple registrations per person (and won't be discouraged), I just would like to offer this in such a way as that users can keep the profiles tied together, switch easily and only have to log in once.

The two approaches I've thought up so far include:

- One (`User` model + `SiteProfile` model) pair and many `PublicProfile` models per person. `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is set to point to the `SiteProfile` model. Issue with this is that I can't easily use per-object permissions: these will be set on the `User` object and not the public profile, thus permissions to see a page for "PublicProfileA" will also be applied to when the user is masquerading as "PublicProfileB".
- One `Account` model and many (`User` model + `UserProfile` model) pairs per person. `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` is set to point to the `UserProfile` model. This would have the added benefit of the permissions working as intended, and that I can simply have a Custom Backend that will switch users by authenticating a user by if they are currently logged in as another user that has the same `Account` object as the Foreign Key. Authentication would happen by reading fields on the `Account` object though, which would mean the `password` field on every `User` object would be wasted.
- As above, but subclassing `Account` from `User`. I've been advised strongly against this though (for reasons unclear).

Is there any pitfalls or better approaches to this? Ultimately, should I use the built-in `User` model as the one-per-person model that identifies a group of public facing profiles (of which these profiles have a FK back to the `User` object), or use it as the profile itself, linking back to a single `Account` object for each person?

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide a little more context on what these different profiles will offer? e.g. If you were building an ecommerce site, your users could have personal accounts and corporate accounts. This would affect for example discount policy, order quantity/volume etc. This info would help in making a more informed suggestion.

Comment: Wow, apologies for this being so late! This is for a social site, one function being a role-play element. All accounts are 'equal' in regards they won't have seperate 'types', there'is no such thing as a Corperate or Personal account, simply 'Members'. Also, there will be custom authentication backends written anyway, as the built-in Django auth backend doesn't meet my needs. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think the best approach would be to have one and only one User per person and several PublicProfile objects that they can "switch" between.  This gives the benefit of only one username/password for them and seems to make the most sense with how Django's auth typically works.